# Is »lecker dabei« commonly used?

Tags: word-usage, colloquial

I recently heard a child refer to an ice cream as

> lecker dabei

which I understood as equivalent to "really delicious". If this is so, how does this use of "dabei" sound to a German? Is it fairly common usage? Is it acceptable, or does it sound silly?

Comment: please give you question a title which describes the problem.

Comment: Please provide more context, e.g. the whole exchange. On its own, its gibberish. In context, one might be able to think of something (we refer to things as "lecker dabei" if they go well together, e.g. "Der Kakao ist lecker dabei" when talking about drinking hot chocolate while also eating icecream).

Comment: how can it mean delicious, when a direct english translation seems to look more like "lick with"

Comment: @user610620 I don't know where you got that translation, bit its completely wrong.

Comment: "lecker" is licking. "dabei" or at least "bei" is a conjunction like "with"

Comment: @user610620: No, it's not. "Lecken" is "licking".

Comment: Yes, more context, and how old was the child. A child of 2 speaks very inaccurate, while at 13, it should speak right, most of the time.

Comment: I suppose this is just some (weird) expression used in that specific familiy (probably from the north of Germany). It is not a common way of talking.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the child said "Leckerei"?

> 2. etwas Leckeres, besonders etwas Süßes

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leckerei

"lecker dabei" does not make much sense in any context that I can think of.

Comment: I suppose it's some common expression in that family (sounds like they were from some northern part of Germany). It's not a common German expression in any case.

Answer (score 1):

"Lecker" means "yummy" or "delicious", and the word "dabei" (which means something like "with it" or "at the same time") always refers to something that was mentioned before.

So "lecker dabei" in itself can't mean "really delicious".

Without context it isn't possible to say what "dabei" referred to in this case, or whether it was just babbling.

Examples for uses of "lecker dabei" (all of them are colloquial):

> Ich mag das Eis, und die Waffel ist auch lecker dabei. (= bei dem Eis)

> Ich sehe an der Halfpipe gerne den Skatern zu, und ein Eis schmeckt lecker dabei. (= beim Zusehen)

> Schokoladeneis ist so ungesund, aber dabei so lecker.
> Schokoladeneis ist so ungesund, aber so lecker dabei. (= dabei meaning "at the same time" plus sloppy change of word order)

Answer (score -6):

I can't tell you how it sounds to a German because I'm not German, but I can tell you how it sounds to someone from Austria where people speak German too:

It sounds absolutely terrible.

For Austrian ears it sounds typical German, where *»German«* doesn't refer to the language, but to the country. The word *»lecker«* gets used also in Austria more and more, but still a big majority of people in Austria think it is an ugly and disgusting word (although it means the opposite of *disgusting*).

There are lots of words that are quite common in Germany, but rarely used in Austria because for people from Austria they sound ugly. The most disgusting German-German word is *»Quark«* (curd cheese, the stuff you use to make cheese cake) which is *»Topfen«* in Austria and Bavaria. You will not find any package of *»Quark«* in any supermarket in Austria. People in Austria wouldn't buy it because of its ugly name. The very same kind of cheese is sold here under the label *»Topfen«*.

The word *»lecker«* also ranks very high in the list of words which sound disgusting to people from Austria. The name of this phenomenon is *»Sprachekel«* (*language disgust*).

Other words people in Austria don't like are (in brackets the Austrian version):

> hochgehen (hinauf gehen), fegen (kehren), Kissen (Polster), gucken (schauen), Mütze (Haube), pusten (blasen), Quatsch (Blödsinn), Schippe (Schaufel), Strippe (Schnur), Tüte (Sackerl), tschüß (servus), ...

---

Also the word *dabei,* used in some specific constructions, sounds ugly to people from Austria. Here are examples for the specific construction I mean:

> Schnitzel mit Tunke **dabei**
> Schweinebraten mit Knödeln **dabei**
> Sachertorte mit Sahne **dabei**

In Austria these examples turn into these versions:

> Schnitzel<sup>1</sup>
> Schwein**s**braten mit Knödel
> Sachertorte mit Schlagobers<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Austrian people don't eat their schnitzel with dip or sauce*</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>*»Sahne« is another word people from Austria don't like*</sub>

It is enough to use the word »mit« (»with«). You don't have to add »dabei« (in this context: »attached«).

In Germany some people also have a tendency to add *»dabei«* in other situations too:

> Viel Spaß **dabei!** (instead of »Viel Spaß!«)

Or when a simple *»mit«* would sound better (at least for Austrian ears):

> Hast du einen Regenschirm **dabei?** (doesn't sound well)
> Hast du einen Regenschirm **mit?** (much better)

And so,

> lecker dabei

is a combination that sounds so terribly ugly and disgusting for someone from Austria, that it is simply unacceptable.

Comment: This is a rant, and doesn't even answer the question. And "Schweinebraten mit Knödeln dabei", and I don't really know where you expect to find *that*? Not on any menu I have ever seen all around the republic. The last two example you give are semantically different. "Viel Spaß dabei!" is the wish for fun for an exact activity that was specified beforehand in the conversation. "Viel Spaß" is a *generic* wish. Although in practice often interchangeable, they aren't the same and have slightly different emphasis.

Comment: And for the umbrella, "hast du einen Regenschirm mit" provokes the though  "Mit was? Senf?".

Comment: The constructions with *dabei* in the end are chiefly used in the *Ruhrgebiet* and maybe in Rhineland, but are definitely *not* characteristic for the German spoken in Germany. Also, *Tunke* may be some regional word for *Soße*, but of very limited extent, too. Furthermore, that list of yours makes me shiver. Do you say *Stempelpolster* because *Stempelkissen* gives you utter disgust? Can you only accept *Die Bombe geht hinauf* because *Die Bombe geht hoch* is a no-go? Or would you prefer a *heißer Kehrer* because a *heißer Feger* turns you off? Plus, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This answer is not only off-topic, it is very subjective and provocative. Mütze, Tschüss, lecker and Kissen are common in western parts of Austria. Heck, there are even regions in Tyrol near the German border where Austrians say "ne" and "gucken". I'm all for highlighting the heterogeneity of the German language. But you can present this in a less arrogant manner.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist nur Quark.